# what does Cross compiler have to do with OS?

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation

I was trying to understand why we needed cross compilers, I found out that if we need to generate a binary on a different platform from where we have the build environment we need a cross compiler which generates the binary for the target platform.
My question is, does cross compiler have anything to do with the Operating system?
example If I am running the compiler on a windows machine with a ARM processor, can the binary generated be straight away run on Linux machine running on ARM processor? does the compiler add any specific wrapper around the binary for the operating system to understand it?

Thanks for the replies

Comment: it all depends on which compiler you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Binary formats are often OS specific, and they in turn touch codegeneration:

- Anything related to dynamic linking may be OS specific. How to define or call a symbol in a dynamic library, tables to prepare etc.
- Relocation and avoiding it (think position independent code generation).
- The exact ABI might have influence (e.g. stack alignment for SSE)
- Resources.
- TLS implementation
- rules about symbols (e.g. some binary formats prefix all symbols with "_"
- generation of assembler meta statements like sections.

Besides that the compiler usually instruments the call to the linker, and that might require extra detail knowledge too.

So it is certainly a form of cross. Cross enough to have to build a separate compiler? That is harder to say. But nobody ever said that two different architectures HAD to be two separate binaries either. It is just convention and the result of architectures.

E.g. Free Pascal does not need separate binaries for cross-OS compiling on the same architecture, so the Linux compiler can generate windows binaries. Stronger even, the Linux compiler has the win32/64 assembler, archiver and linker for the corresponding architecture built-in.